# (APACHE) Apache blocking my acess to WEBSITE

Tags: php, android, apache, cakephp, titanium-mobile

I am having some couple problems with apache that is blocking my ip adress.
In my company we have an Android App made in Titanium SDK that constantly makes alot of server requests, most of this requests is GET requests, but we have around 40000 images to download , so we do 40000 requests in server constantly for each device in the same IP , after some time , the IP will block, but when I try access from other IP , it works fine. However, when i restart the apache server , the access got back again. There's any way to configure the apache to not block my ip in apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `.htaccess` file, then modify it like this (If you don't have `.htaccess file`, create it) :

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 96.xxx.xx.xxx #your IP address
allow from 97.xx.xxx.xxx #your client's IP address
```

Comment: I did it, but i can't deny access from all , because i have users in the entire country , but only in my company i am having this issue because there's alot of users doing requests from the same IP

Comment: Otherwise, I just allowed the IP and i think it fixed , thanks

Comment: Cool... please vote up the answer...